# Babel Import/Export Dependency Conflicts

Tags: visual-studio-code, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I'm trying to use javascript ES7 to set up my base graphql server. My application crashes when I do npm run from my terminal. I believe I've installed too many babel packages, causing dependency contradictions. Does the babel-preset-env cover everything I need from babel? Why does babel-preset-stage-0 conflict with the env?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: ES7 (ES2016) was released two years ago. I think you may be referring to experimental features which have not been released yet.